# SQL Update Using From

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

I know this is a contrived example so please do not jump all over me for the uselessness of the code. This is an issue in more complex chunk of code but I wanted to isolate the I am having.

The error I am getting is 'SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended'. Any ideas? I am using SQL Developer by the way.

Once again...this is a contrived example and while the join is pointless in this case it is not in the more complex example.

Here is the code:

```
Update u
set first300pa = 1
from GameData_ME u
inner join 
GameData_ME v on u.pitchandeventid = v.pitchandeventid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20200925232958/http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2008/06/18/oracle-update-with-join-again.aspx) says,

> Those who transitioned from SqlServer
> to Oracle might find the absence of
> the UPDATE FROM a significant loss.

Fortunately, the blog continues by showing a lot of the power of Oracle's `UPDATE` and how to use it to perform the tasks you need (but it won't be with a `FROM` clause in the `UPDATE` statement... not in Oracle!-).

Comment: thanks...i had a feeling this was the case. back to the drawing board i guess.